# How to deserialize a json file with multidimensional array to convert it to object in c#

Tags: c#, json, multidimensional-array

I have the following Json file

```
[
    {
        "photos": [
            {
                "photo": "http://example.com/media/origin/11820846/photo_80_4_.jpg",
                "photo_order": 1,
                "caption": "photo_80_4_"
            }
        ],
        "id": "11820846"
    }
],
[
    {
        "photos": [
            {
                "photo": "http://example.com/media/new_images/
   bookingpal/united%20arab%20emirates/
   12564676/product65093-015.jpg",
                "photo_order": 1,
                "caption": ""
            }
        ],
        "id": "12564676"
    }
]
```

The original file is longer but basically it repeats.

With the following code I can see the data for the first array but it fails when it gets to the second array.

Why?

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        using (var st = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\mc\Desktop\photojson.txt")) {

            string Json = st.ReadToEnd();
            List<TVID> IdList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TVID>>(Json);

            foreach (var ids in IdList) {
                Console.WriteLine(ids.ID);
                foreach (var myphoto in ids.photos) {
                    Console.WriteLine(myphoto.Photo + "," + myphoto.Photo_order + "," +
                                      myphoto.Caption);
                    Console.Read();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class TVPhotos {
        public string Photo { get; set; }
        public string Photo_order { get; set; }
        public string Caption { get; set; }
    }

    public class TVID {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public List<TVPhotos> photos { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that the JSON snippet you posted is invalid according to [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: Also, what does "fails" mean?

Comment: It just get the error Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: ,. Path '', line 23, position 3.  which is the comma that separates the arrays.

Comment: unsurprising, since up to that point it's valid JSON and then... it isn't. Compare with [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/)'s result.

Comment: (Perhaps you wanted an array of arrays?)

Answer (score 0):

To fix the error you mentioned in the comments ("Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content") you need to surround the JSON with square brackets as below:

```
[
    [
        {
            "photos": [
                {
                    "photo": "http://example.com/media/origin/11820846/photo_80_4_.jpg",
                    "photo_order": 1,
                    "caption": "photo_80_4_"
                }
            ],
            "id": "11820846"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "photos": [
                {
                    "photo": "http://example.com/media/new_images/bookingpal/united%20arab%20emirates/12564676/product65093-015.jpg",
                    "photo_order": 1,
                    "caption": ""
                }
            ],
            "id": "12564676"
        }
    ]
]
```

And to deserialize this you can use **List< List< TVID > >** such as:

```
using (var st = new StreamReader(@"sample1.json"))
{
    string Json = st.ReadToEnd();
    List<List<TVID>> IdListList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<TVID>>>(Json);

    foreach (var IdList in IdListList)
    {
        foreach (var ids in IdList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ids.ID);
            foreach (var myphoto in ids.photos)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(myphoto.Photo + "," + myphoto.Photo_order + "," +
                                  myphoto.Caption);
                Console.Read();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Looking at the JSON I think a single array would do the same job but if you can't change the JSON the above changes should make it work.