# C# Deserialize JSON array

Tags: c#, json, multidimensional-array

I am having an issue deserializing and defining this JSON structure would be great to get some assistance. I have reverted this back to last known working position because I am just going off the rails here.

my JSON stucture is:

```
[{
"name": "Name1",
"description": "Description of this process",
"Location": "ANY",
"SubItems": [{
    "name": "sub1",
    "required": true,
    "description": "This is a short description"
}, {
    "name": "sub2",
    "required": true,
    "description": "This is a short description"
}, {
    "name": "sub3",
    "required": true,
    "description": "This is a short description"
}],
"outputs": [{
    "name": "out1",
    "required": false
}, {
    "name": "exit code",
    "required": false
}]
}, {
   "name": "Name2",
   "description": "This is a short description",
   "Location": "ANY",
   "SubItems": [{
       "name": "sub1",
       "required": false,
       "description": "This is a short description"
      }]
   }]
```

Here are my C# Json definitions that were last working.

```
public class JsonObject
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string ProcessName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("description")]
    public string ProcessDescription { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Location")]
    public string KnownLocation { get; set; }
}
```

I am only capturing a couple of definitions at the moment for testing.

Here is my deserializing object

```
var Object = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <List<JsonObject>>(txt);
            foreach (JsonObject JsonObject in Object)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name: " + JsonObject.ProcessName);
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Description: " +JsonObject.ProcessDescription);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
```

So as I had stated, I can get at least the first 3 top-most level JSON elements in the output. The problem starts when I start trying to get the "SubItems" and "outputs"

I followed the structure of the below linked post and tried very hard to understand it, but after a while I realized that solution is not for this issue. I simply have a multi-dimentional array JSON object. Literally has a top tier, and 2 sub tiers

I attempted to try and do...

```
List<List<JsonObject>>Object = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <List<List<JsonObject>>>(txt);
```

and tried to have 2 lists of the same with different names with 3 sets of JSON Definitions.

and implemented the tiered foreach loops, but then I wasn't able to access the definitions for the top most JSON, and nothing was writing for the actual elements for "SubItems"

What I need is to get to each object, really.

[How to deserialize a json file with multidimensional array to convert it to object in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32896228/how-to-deserialize-a-json-file-with-multidimensional-array-to-convert-it-to-obje)

Related Issue

Comment: It does not look like your array is multidimensional, just your JsonObject has an array inside.

Comment: That JSON is invalid.  Upload to http://jsonlint.com/ and you will see various errors.  Can you [edit] your question to include JSON that [reproduces](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) the problem?

Comment: Raderick, that is the definition of multi-dimentional array.

Comment: dbc- I chunked it out from a giant JSON list. I do not create the JSON nor can I control it or edit it, so please just assume that the JSON is properly formatted. Im not having an issue with JSON I am having an issue parsing the JSON array object in C# so this is more of a C# coding question

Comment: dbc sure, you want me to provide you with a .exe you can run?

Comment: dbc, I fixed the JSON, just needed to remove a comma at the end....

Comment: Multidimensional array: `[[0,1],[2,3],[4,5]]`. Your code: `[{prop:[0,1]},{prop:[2,3]}]`. It's not a multidimensional array.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a multi dimentional array. Just an array objects containing arrays.
So your model can be as follows

```
public class SubItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Required { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Output
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Required { get; set; }
}

public class JsonObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public List<SubItem> SubItems { get; set; }
    public List<Output> Outputs { get; set; }
}
```

and you can deserialize as

```
 var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JsonObject>>(jsonstring);
```

*PS: you can use `JsonProperty` to decorate that model as you do in question*

Comment: Hi L.B thank you for your solution! I implemented this model as you indicated above.  So when I run this, the SubItems are blank as are the Outputs.
So I tried a foreach loop through SubItems inside the foreach loop which breaks with: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Also, whenever I wipe out the JsonPropery reference, I get a blank list back.

Comment: Progress! I have 2 foreach loops inside the main loop. 
foreach(blah obj in Object) {
      foreach (var Inputs in Object.InputsParams) { //output to console}
      foreach (var outputs in Object.OutputParams { //output to console}
}
I'm getting back some data finally however, not all these Json Objects have "Output" and my code keeps choking. actually Im not even sure. I just know that Outputs dont always exist or even listed in the JSON model in the return.

Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @JeremyWinslow  `I just know that Outputs dont always exist or even listed in the JSON model  in the return` Then why don't you add a simple null checek to your code writing to console?